# How to install Windows 8 after Linux with UEFI

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I have an Asus Zenbook UX32LN with Linux Mint installed on the whole 256GB SSD.

How do I install Windows 8 alongside Linux ? The first step is of course to make a new big-enough partition for Windows using GParted but I am not sure of what to do after Windows is installed.

Will the UEFI boot partition be able to detect the two OS and give a grub screen with choices ?

My current configuration:

- /dev/sda1 fat32 /boot/efi 512MiB
- /dev/sda2 ext4  / 230.09GiB
- /dev/sda3 linux-swap 7.89GiB

Comment: Once Windows 8 is installed you will find that you won't be able to boot to Linux... you'll need to re-run the grub install so that it picks up both your OSes and you'll then be prompted at each boot which OS you want :)

Comment: install both operatings systems like normal, booting to an EFI enabled installation disks, thus install both operating systems so they will boot in EFI mode.  After that is done use the grub utility to repair it depending on the installation order.